# passing values between servlet and java file

Tags: java, spring, servlets, tiles

I've one spring controller which is setting some values to request and shows a jsp page. For the view part we use tiles. The result page has 3 parts, header , content and footer jsp's. 
This header jsp use a java file and i want to access the attributes created by the first spring controller from this file. Is there any way to do that without using session? 
When I tried request.getAttribute, it gives null. I think it's because it's not an immediate file after the request values setting.

Comment: do u have formbean for your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as everything runs in the same request and the controller code is executed before the view part, `setAttribute()` should work. To debug issues like that, use a `Filter` which dumps the request URL and attributes to the console or the log.

If those calls are in different requests, you have two options: The session and a Spring bean (use a session bean or your own implementation). I prefer beans since they are type safe and they allow me to separate my code from the Servlet API which is complex to test.

Comment: I can see the value in the filter

Comment: And your view code runs before the filter finishes? If so, then someone deletes the value or the view gets a new request instance that is created, for example, by another filter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll really need to put some code to get a code answer but unless you're using JSP scriptlets I'm guessing this is a Java bean that you're using in the header. This of course cannot access the request (hence the session) nor should it really. What you probably want to do is convert it to a tag library if you want it to have access to the request/session.